# Angular 6 get method on forms

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

So I've been delving into the source code for Angular 6 to help better my understanding.

The get method is like so

```
get(path: Array<string | number> | string): AbstractControl | null;
```

Which exists on and AbstractClass with Abstract method of AbstractControl, which in turn the formGroup inherits from which is what I'm using to structure my form.

Now I can access the nested children formControls/Groups within the parent forms one of two ways, I can drill down through the

`form.controls.formGroupName.controls.formControlName.value`

Or I can go through the

```
form.values.formGroupName.formControlName
```

The second being shorter but but either require to go through form.values or form.controls.

How is it that `form.get('formGroup.formName')` seems to skip the control or the value field, or doesn't explicitly state it as far as I can see?